# How to pass multiple parameter in hive script

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql

employee:
[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4GrW.jpg)

I want to fetch records of year=2016 by running hive script sample.hql.

```
use octdb;
select * from '${hiveconf:table}' where year = '${hiveconf:year}';

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive -hiveconf table='employee', year=2016 -f sample.hql
```

But i am getting error NoViableAltException(307@[]).......

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the `--hiveconf` option twice:

```
hive --hiveconf table=employee --hiveconf year=2016 -f sample.hql
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Error:
NoViableAltException(307@[])
FAILED: ParseException line 2:14 cannot recognize input near ''employee,'' 'where' 'year' in join source
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.

Comment: You are still using a comma after `employee`; remove it. There is no table named `employee,`.

Comment: Removed but still the same error :-(
Multiple parameter now i can pass like hive -hiveconf year=2016 -hiveconf id=1 -f sample.hql
But how to pass TABLE name too while running .hql script

Answer (score 4):

You should use `--hivevar` instead with newer Hive versions. Earlier, developers were able to set configuration using `--hiveconf` and it was also used for variables. However, later `--hivevar` was implemented to have separate namespace for variables as mentioned in [HIVE-2020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2020).

Use following with beeline

```sh
beeline --hivevar table=employee --hivevar year=2016 -f sample.hql
```

With this, in the Hive script file you can access this variables directly or using hivevar namespace like below.

```sql
select * from ${table};
select * from ${hivevar:table};
```

Please, note that you may need to specify URL string using `-u <db_URL>` option.

Answer (score 1):

By doing R&D found the correct answer, ${hiveconf:table} should define in script without ' '.
sample.hql:-

```
use ${hiveconf:database};

   select * from ${hiveconf:table} where year = ${hiveconf:year};
```

Running sample.hql

```
[cloudera@quickstart shell]$ hive -hiveconf database=octdb -hiveconf table=employee -hiveconf year=2016 -f sample.hql
```

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
OK

```
Time taken: 1.484 seconds
OK
1       A       2016
2       B       2016
4       D       2016
```

Time taken: 4.423 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables can also be achieved through "hivevar" along with "hiveconf".

Here is the difference:

The hiveconf namespace was added and **(--hiveconf)** should be used to set Hive configuration values.

The hivevar namespace was added and **(--hivevar)** should be used to define user variables.

Using hiveconf will also work, but isn't recommended for variable substitution as hivevar is explicitly created for that purpose.

```
set hivevar:YEAR=2018;
SELECT * from table where year=${YEAR};

hive --hiveconf var='hello world' -e '!echo ${hiveconf:var};'
-- this will print: hello world
```